# runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0x000000000000 overflowed to 0xffffffffffffffff (basic_string.h)

Tags: c++, string

The question is to find the largest common prefix strings amongst the array of string.

Example 1:

Input: ["flower","flow","flight"]

Output: "fl"

This is what I have tried till now.

```
class Solution {
public:
string longestCommonPrefix(const vector<string>& v) {
    if ( v.empty() )
     {
        return 0;
     }
   string  smin = *min_element(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                 [] (const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { 
                     return s1.length() < s2.length(); }
                 );
    string str="";
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<smin.size(); i++){
        str+=smin[i];
        for(j=0; j<v.size(); j++){
            if(v[j].find(str)==string::npos){                    
                str=str.substr(0, str.length() - 1);
                return str;
            }                
        }
    }
    return str;
}
};
```

Expected results have been given as an example above.

What I got as an error message is -:

```
Runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0x000000000000 overflowed to 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I have looked into similar answer for this and tried to implement them but the error isn't going. Please can somebody help me with this.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code you've shown. The problem likely lies in the code you haven't shown. Show a [mcve]

Comment: Using `std::string::find` is a bit wasteful here. At `i = 1` you already know that the first character was a match. Also, it will find any non-prefix ocurrence... Lastly, `smin` can be `const&` and declare `i` and `j` in the loops.

Comment: Searching for unrelated answers won't help. You need to learn to make a [mcve], and you need to learn to use your debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty string in the vector.  At some point you calculate length minus 1.  Then use it for the end index substr.

In general, you need to learn to use a debugger, which will tell you exactly what line you got the error and what the variables look like on that line.